# After deploying flutter web project UI is not rendering properly

Tags: html, flutter, rendering, canvaskit

[image]

I am getting this while running on localhost
but i am getting following result after deploying

[image]

i tried with both 'html' and 'canvaskit' but getting same result.

Comment: Something is wrong with your deployment :). Maybe you forgot to include some files. We can't help you by looking at these images. Do you see some errors in your browser console?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.